# Updating address in Blue Card - Germany

Tags: germany, blue-card

I am a Blue card holder. Existing address is printed on my blue card. I am planning to shift to a new apartment. What are the procedures to change the address?

Should take appointment from Auslanderbehörde and submitted application there? How long it will take to get it done?.

Initially it took 6 weeks to get my blue card after submitting my application. Will this be same for updating address also? ( The chip card to be reprinted?)

Comment: Important for those who are planning to move to a different job location of the same company, see this: https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/20366/same-job-and-salary-but-change-of-location-company-has-many-offices-inside-ger/21598#21598

Answer (score 3):

You need to go to the local Bürgeramt (not Ausländerbehörde) with the signed rent contract. It takes only couple of minutes to update the address on your Bluecard with a new sticker.

Comment: The question is about updating address in blue card after address registration in Bürgeramt.

Comment: I understand. They do it on place.

Comment: should I take appointment to do so or directly walk in there?

Comment: It's up to you.

Comment: Ausländerbehörde will also do it, but Bürgeramt might be easier in terms of getting the appointment.

Comment: Can you give me the link of getting an appointment for Berlin? I can't find the correct service in the website, there is a lot...

Comment: Hello, can you give me the link to book an appointment? I couldn't find it.
@MohammadrezaYektamaram do you already have it?

Comment: No, I did not :( @JA9

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, you should go to your local Gemeinde or Auslanderbehörde. They will give you a form, and your landlord will fill it out and sign it. Then you take this form back to them.
2. No, it will take only few minutes. They will cover the old address with a sticker and put the new one. No new card will be issued.

Comment: Can I do it with new Anmeldung also, instead of filling form with landlord?

Comment: Also, should I take appointment to do so or directly walk in there?

Comment: @Johnykutty No appointment is needed, but you might need to wait in the line.