# Same Job and Salary But Change of Location (Company Has Many Offices) Inside Germany

Tags: germany, blue-card

I have a German BlueCard (for the last 2 months) which I got at city X, **which is one of my company's several locations**. Now my company HQ is in city Y (both X and Y are inside Germany, different states) - will this affect my German BlueCard? The job, position, salary remain exactly same with no changes whatsoever.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Updating address in Blue Card - Germany](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/17652/updating-address-in-blue-card-germany)

Comment: No, as the company has not moved, they are moving me from location A to B.

Comment: Yes, then if only you moved to another city, this question is really a duplicate of the one I cited. As already answered there, you just need to register at the corresponding Bürgeramt after moving to the new address. Nothing else is needed. If one decides to resettle within Germany (i.e., to avoid drive/travel from city X to city Y), then, disregarding of immigration status, one needs to register at the new flat within 2 weeks after starting living there. De-registration from the old flat and updating address on the Blue Card  can be done there simultaneously.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**Update 2021:** The other answer is not correct, even changing job location requires a re-permission and form fill-up from the Job Authority and re-verification.

It is easy to prove, let us have a look in the documentation that you had to fill for Blue Card:

[image]

Now let us jump to section 5:

[image]

Translation:

**5. Work location**

- Employee is employed in ____________________________.
- Employee is employed at alternating work/employment locations

Unless you employer had selected the second option, `Employee is employed at alternating work/employment locations` during your initial Blue Card application, you need to ask for permission for an location change. If your employer did select second option - yay!

Future readers, please verify any change by writing to the immigration office. Laws and requirements can change any day!

**Do not rely on this answer!**

Comment: This answer would be more persuasive if it contained or referenced an authoritative, governmental source for the information.

Answer (score 0):

The linked official websites suggest you do need approval:

> Should any work conditions change which are specifically mentioned in
> your residence title, temporary residence permit for asylum seekers
> (Aufenthaltsgestattung) or temporary suspension of deportation
> (Duldung), the relevant provisions must generally be adapted. In such
> cases, permission must again be obtained from the Berlin Immigration
> Office.
>
> This is not necessary, however, if
>
> - only the name of your
>   employer changes, i.e. the name of the company, but the other work
>   conditions named in the job description (occupation, working hours,
>   place of work etc.) remain the same or
> - the name of your occupation
>   changes, although the employment modalities continue to correspond to
>   those in the job description. The same applies in the event of
>   promotions where the same employment is continued but only the name of
>   the occupation changes and the income increases.

https://service.berlin.de/dienstleistung/326856/en/

https://www.berlin.de/einwanderung/_assets/labo-4316a-merkblatt-fuer-arbeitnehmer-und-arbeitnehmerinnen.pdf