# Update residential address in Blue card - Munich - COVID-19 times

Tags: germany, eu

I would like to update my residential address on my Blue card. The *Anmeldung* is already done.

I have mailed the Foreigners' office who asked me to call a number that is out of service. And since COVID-19 we cannot turn up at the government's office to check with them.

Any one who faced a similar situation or any tips on how to follow up on this?

Comment: You already had contact with them and they have you a phone number, so contact them again and tell them that it is not reachable and they will give you a new one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Updating address in Blue Card - Germany](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/17652/updating-address-in-blue-card-germany)